# Async and recursion in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Beginning with **express** and **mongoose** i often need to do some batch operations on collections.
However it usually involves callbacks which is a pain given how concurrency is coded in nodejs.
so basically

```
//given a collection C 
var i = 0;
var doRecursive = function(i){
    if(i<C.length){
      C[i].callAsync(err,result){
        i=+1;
        return doRecursive(i);
       }
    }else{
      return done();
    }
}
doRecursive(i);
```

Now i dont remember what is the max stack before i get a stackover flow with node , but i guess with 10 000 elements , it wont do.
I wonder if there are other ways to handle this, if yes , what are they?
thanks

Comment: Well, asynchronous functions will help with stack overflows as the callback will be in a different call stack. But, by breaking out into a different stack, it renders `return` rather useless.

Comment: take a look at [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the goal is to iterate an collection asynchronously, there are numerous control flow libraries available.

A good example is [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) and its [`reduce` function](https://github.com/caolan/async#reduce):

```
async.reduce(C, 0, function (memo, item, callback) {
    item.callAsync(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, memo + result);
        }
    });
}, function (err, result) {
    // ...
});
```

Note: It's not entirely clear what value you wanted to get from `doRecursion`, so this just uses addition for an example.

Comment: I know async. does async has a way to generalize recursion so recursion can be written in a "prettier" fashion ? People are telling me there should be no stackoverflow issue with recursion and async calls, i need to test it to be sure. EDIT : i see you are using Async.reduce , interesting ,did not know about that one.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can simply self-iterate instead of true recursion, since you're not drilling into a deep object:

```
function doRecursive (C, i){
    i=i||0;
    if(i<C.length){
       C[i].callAsync(err, function(result){
          doRecursive(C, ++i);
       });
    }else{
       done();
    }
};

doRecursive(C);
```

this does not create a tall stack if the code functions as labeled. 
i localized C so that it executes faster and is potentially re-usable on other collections.
the pattern also makes it easy to defer it for long-running operations, just by changing

```
doRecursive(C, ++i);
```

to

```
setTimeout( doRecursive.bind(this, C, ++i), 50 );
```